# Need to specify order of HTTP request elements in Node.js

Tags: node.js, http, https, npm-request

I am trying to establish a persistent connection between our node (`express.js`) server and a vendor server.  We are currently using the "`request"` library, though we can easily move to something else.  `https://www.npmjs.com/package/request`

The vendor has told us that the body of the Post request (to their API) needs to come before things like `Content-Type, charset,` etc.  So like this:

```
"POST / HTTP/1.1\r\nREQUEST_JSON_API: **{\"REQUEST_TYPE\":\"STATUS\"}** \r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\ncharset: utf-8\r\nUser-Agent.."
```

Instead of how it's currently coming across:

```
"POST / HTTP/1.1\r\nhost: xxx.x.xxx.1:3000\r\naccept: application/json\r\ncontent-type: application/json\r\ncontent-length: 25\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n **{\"REQUEST_TYPE\":\"STATUS\"}**"
```

Does anyone have any advice on how to tackle this please?

Comment: I guess you just want to send it manually. As you wrote here. %)P

Comment: Assuming that we don't have time to write our own library, is there anything you can recommend?

Comment: You don’t need a library. [Just use `net`.](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net_createconnection).

Comment: That makes no sense that the body of a POST would come before the headers.  That's not HTTP.  Your first example is not showing that at all.  It's showing a custom header named `REQUEST_JSON_API:` that has some JSON as the value of that header.  It is not showing any body to the POST as the body comes after `\r\n\r\n` and you don't have one of those in your first example.

Comment: You should be able to specify a custom header named `REQUEST_JSON_API: ` easily with the `request()` library.  Did you try that?

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks I will try.  What I posted here was the result of their debug output. We don't have access to the server.  For all I know this isn't even the problem and someone is just guessing that's what it is.  Also yes if this is the problem, it isn't following the protocol as I understand it

Comment: It looks to me like you're misunderstanding what they want.  You are attempting to put the data in the POST body, but apparently they want the data in a custom header.  That's legal HTTP, just different than what you were trying to send it.  You can do that just fine with any normal HTTP library such as the `request()` library.  You just have to construct the proper custom HTTP header and specify that on the POST request.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks!  I've never run into this before for json.  I will do some research on what the advantages might be?  I suppose there must have been a reason.  Hopefully also this fixes the problem

Comment: No, I don't think it's a good design, just the way they did it so you have to create the request that way to get it to work.  No need to research advantages.

Comment: @jfriend00 thank you very much!  We are now at least being heard by the server.  Other obstacles remain, but this one is resolved.

Comment: @jfriend00 update for the sake of completing the loop:  It turns out that they had attempted to create their own custom network stack.  I was able to convince them to upgrade their c framework (which was so old it didn't support modern keepalive) and add a proper library which supports sockets.  They had been trying to hack their way into a persistent connection.  Weird stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll turn my comments into an answer since it apparently solved your original problem:

It looks to me like you're misunderstanding what they want. You are attempting to put the data in the POST body, but apparently they want the JSON data in a custom header called `REQUEST_JSON_API` with nothing in the POST body. That's different than what you were trying to send it.

You can do that just fine with any normal HTTP library such as the `request()` library. You just have to construct the proper custom HTTP header and specify that on the POST request.

You can see how to set custom headers with the `request()` library [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#custom-http-headers).

Comment: I don't know why you were downvoted.  I understand why I was as I was misunderstanding the problem.  Anyways... It does seem to have worked for us?  I think you correctly identified my misunderstanding and proposed a workable solution, in an admirably respectful and informative way.  Thank you again!